# Can a thesis contain preface?

Tags: phd, thesis, writing

Usually preface is written in books and myself personally have not seen it in a thesis.

But, can a master's or doctoral thesis contain a preface?

Thanks

Comment: There are no universal rules for what can or can't go in a thesis.  Your institution might have rules, however.

Comment: my institute has no prescribed thesis format

Comment: Is there anything you want to put into the preface, but you don't want to write in the introduction chapter?

Comment: yes, there are a few things, which in my opinion are not suitable for introduction or abstract

Comment: As long as your advisor okay with it, I think you can, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This was going to be a comment, but then I realized it actually answers the question that was asked.*

The following 2004 Ph.D. dissertation at Utrecht University has a preface on pp.
 xi-xviii, so the answer is YES.

[**Ideas and Explorations : Brouwer's Road to Intuitionism**](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/90)

However, the question you possibly want answered is whether a Ph.D. dissertation at *YOUR* university can have a preface. To find the answer, you can ask someone knowledgeable about the specific dissertation format rules at your university, or you could visit the library shelves where recent Ph.D. dissertations are shelved and spend 20-30 minutes quickly flipping through the first few pages of the 100-200 most recent dissertations, keeping in mind that for some universities the answer might be department-specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's your work, so unless there are rules to the opposite, I would say go ahead. Many theses contain acknowledgments in a preface, for example -- most of the time thanking real people, but sometimes also their dog, a brewery, or imagined events. Read through enough theses and you will get the idea.

So, see whether there are rules, and if there are none talk to your adviser what is appropriate. Beyond that, *you're* the author and decide how best you want to say what you want to say.